# How to make scroll bar go up/down with arrow keys?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete

I am creating a Custom Autocomplete in react and it has some issue which I would like to resolved. When I search any keyword and use my arrow key (up/down) then scroll bar is not going with it.

I created minimal example [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-autocomplete-stln89?file=/src/App.js)

How can I fix this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you are going to attach a link to your code, please also attach your code to the question. I recommend you check out [ask] and [edit] your question to include your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have made the changes to your codesandbox. Hope this helps! https://codesandbox.io/s/react-autocomplete-forked-0o1hll?file=/src/components/Autocomplete.js

Comment: Thank you so much. I faced another problem with this solution, When I use arrow key to move up/down scroll bar of whole page is also changing with the scroll bar of autocomplete.

Comment: Fixed it by adding `block: "nearest"` into `scrollIntoView` Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, you can play with the scrollintoview function and make it how you want it to be. Please upvote if you find the answer helpful.

Comment: @arp You should explain what did you do and why.

Comment: Why are you calling `setChange` for every option in the list?